# Texture doesn't show up in Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

The preview i have using Cycles is looking good but when i go to render it with F12 the texture doesn't show up and a weird white texture appears on my object instead (see the pictures).
[image: The Render Preview]
[image: The Render Result]

I have an UV texture coordinate and it didn't fix the problem.
[image: The Shader Nodes]

I'd like any help i can get, thank you !

Comment: please add the blend file to your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you performe UV unwrapping for your object?

Comment: You need to disable the high poly anvil for rendering. Go to the object properties > visibility > uncheck Render

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you so much i knew it was something stupid like that !

Comment: @Zechodian It's a very common overlook by newcomers, it's not stupid at all. You have to remember that object visibility in the viewport is not linked to its visibility in the final render